# UPDATE PICTURE - How do I display message from a to b and b to a in PHP SQL?

Tags: php, sql, database

How do I display message from a to b and b to a in PHP sql?  Basically this is my table structure for 'Chat log':

```
ID, Userid, Userid2, Email, Email2, Message, and Date_Posted. 
*Note: Userid and Email is = the received
Note: Userid2 and Email2 is = the sender*
```

The link is like `send.php?userid=1&userid2=2` ( to read chat is working fine )

The problem is how do I display the last message for each user like limit 1.

If user **A** login = show link send message to profile **B**

and if user **B** login show link send to profile **A**

### Update

[Refer Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsR58.jpg)

Here is my current sql for display message is working only for one side.

```
<?php
$count=1;
$sel_query="SELECT * from chat_logs where `email` = '$_SESSION[email]' or `email2` = '$_SESSION[email]' ORDER  BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10";
$result = mysql_query($sel_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="white">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%" height="44"></td>
    <td width="9%" valign="top"><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background: #eee no-repeat center; background-size: cover;" src="dp/
<?php if ($row["email"]='$_SESSION[email]'){
echo "" . $row["dp1"]. "";
}
else{
echo "" . $row["dp2"]. "";
} ?>">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="91%" align="left" valign="top"><strong>

<?php if ($row["email"]='$_SESSION[email]'){
echo "" . $row["username"]. "";
}
else{
echo "" . $row["username2"]. "";
} ?>

<a href="sendmessage.php?id=<?php echo $row["userid2"]; ?>&userid2=<?php echo $row["userid"]; ?>"></strong><br><font color="black"><?php echo $row["message1"]; ?></a></a><br><font size="1"><?php echo $row["time1"]; ?></font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<?php $count++; } ?>
```

Comment: You can look it out.. http://github.com/ankitjain28may/openchat

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is Userid synonymous with user A and Userid2 synonymous with user B?

Comment: i have update the photo and mu current sql